# Clojure - How to refer deftype's variables in macros?

Tags: macros, clojure, deftype

When I do

```
(defmacro my-deftype [& code] `(deftype ~@code (toString [this] var1)))
(my-deftype Qqq [var1] Object)
```

it tells `CompilerException ... No such var: mynamespace/var1`

How to refer deftype's variables in macros properly? I want macros to provide a template for methods and avoid mentioning all deftype's variables in each method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Namespace expansion should be prevented by `~'`:

```
(defmacro my-deftype [& code] `(deftype ~@code (toString [~'this] ~'var1)))
(my-deftype Qqq [var1] Object)
```